Returning null from a generic function in dart
In this dart snippet:
// The value 'null' can't be returned from a function with return type 'T' 
// because 'T' is not nullable.
T func1<T>() {
  return null;
}

void func2<T>(T x) {
  print(x);
}
  
void main() {
  String? s = func1();
  func2(null);
}

Both functions use generic T; one tries to treat T as nullable within the function body and fails, the other's caller tries to treat T as nullable and succeeds. I understand the second one, but I am confused by this difference. In both cases, I would argue that T should be nullable because dart docs says that the default type is T extends Object?. The error remains the same even if I change the func1's signature to make T inherit explicitly from nullable object using func1<T extends Object?>.
I can get it to compile by changing the return type to T?, but then why would the docs say that the default is T extends Object?. Is this requirement to specify the type as T? before you can return null just a syntax rule to make it clear to the callers that the return value may be null?
If that is the case, dart allows me to override that rule; even if I keep the return type as T, I can get func1 to return null by changing it to return null as T;. And it runs fine because after all, T extends Object?. This kinda breaks the expectation that a generic function with return type T may not return null. The following code compiles fine, but throws a runtime error as T resolves to String during runtime causing the casting to fail. I understand why that's happening, but why isn't there a way to catch this at compile time?

T func3<T>() {
  return null as T;
}

  
void main() {
  String s = func3();
}

I am sure I am missing something basic about generic functions, and/or how they should be implemented in dart. But I couldn't find any official documentation other than the one I linked. So any input regarding this would be much appreciated.

It's not a rule that T extends object? infers that T will be T?.
No it will be just non-nullable T, except for the parameters of type T they could be T?.
You must explicitly mark the return type as T? even if it implicitly exetends Object?
So, for your example:
You should mark the return type as T? Although it extends Object?
T? func1 <T>(){
  
  return null;
}

and if you have a parameter that may be null, it can accept null because T extends Object? by default. but not the return type (you explicitly make it nullable).
T? func1 <T>(T a){ // a could be passed as nullable or non-nullable
  
  return null;
}

void main() {

  var a = func1(null);
  print(a);
  
}


var a = func1(null); <-- In this statement, what type is inferred for T?

@Dai , passing a null will be acceptable because T extends Object? by default. so the parametrized generic a can accept null as T? although it's of T type.

@Dai the type Null would be inferred for T.

I understand it, but couldn't find any official documentation regarding this anywhere. Also, being able to return null as T from a generic function of type T kind of defeats the purpose of having to "explicitly make the return type nullable with T?"

@Amarghosh i will answer you by asking a question. null as T casting is done successfully because T extends Object? ok ? but if i'm asking you what is the return type of this function, is it T or T?, as a client for that function i don't care about being T extends some nullable or not, so nullability of the return type is stated explicitly to clarify method signature to clients.
